# How to send the mail(jason body contains email details) using api_key and api_secrete in databricks in scala programming language

Tags: scala, azure, smtp, databricks

I need to notify the users whenever there is a error in the databricks scala notebook.How to send the mail(jason body contains email details) using api_key and api_secrete(instead of using smtp i need to use api_key and api_secrete) in databricks in *scala programming language*

Answer (score 0):

You may check out below code for sending emails through Databricks in scala programming language.

```
import java.util.Properties

import java.util.Properties
import javax.mail.{Message, Session}
import javax.mail.internet.{InternetAddress, MimeMessage}

import scala.io.Source

val host = "<YOUR_SMTP>"
val port = "587"

val address = "<YOUR_EMAIL>"
val username = "<YOUR_USERNAME>"
val password = dbutils.secrets.get("<SECRET_SCOPE>", "EMAIL_SMTP_PASSWORD") 

def sendEmail(mailSubject: String, mailContent: String) = {
    val properties = new Properties()
    properties.put("mail.smtp.port", port)
    properties.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true")
    properties.put("mail.smtp.starttls.enable", "true")

    val session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties, null)
    val message = new MimeMessage(session)
    message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(address));
    message.setSubject(mailSubject)
    message.setContent(mailContent, "text/html")


    val transport = session.getTransport("smtp")
    transport.connect(host, username, password)
    transport.sendMessage(message, message.getAllRecipients)
}
```

For more details, refer "[Sending emails in Databricks by using Scala](https://xaviergeerinck.com/scala-email-sending)".

Hope this helps. Do let us know if you any further queries.

Comment: Hi, If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.